# Energy band diagram

Tags: transistors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnC1mE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My question is if I had an arrangement, instead of a transistor npn, an ipn junction where a i is neutral ,p is p-type semiconductor and n is n-type semiconductor, what would be the energy band diagramm? (instead of emitter base collector npn,i have an ipn which i is neutral).

Comment: correct me, but wouldn't the I zone be an isolator?

Comment: i dont think .... for instance ,i means that it doesn't have no Boron or phosphorus elements, it's only silicon (instead of n++,p+,n transistor)

Comment: Using the term *Intrinsic* would be clearer. Using intrinsic material is common - see PIN diodes.

Comment: @PeterSmith exactly! But a PIN diode is a *bad* rectifier (but a great adjustable attenuator), because the lack of holes/free electrons in the intrinsic layer needs to be compensated by migration of the same from the P and N layer, so you need a large DC bias just to "attract" them across the P/I and I/N boundaries. Undoted Silicone doesn't conduct well, and so this transistor won't really work as such – it'll really just look like a resistor connected to the P end of a normal PN diode, if I might make a wild guess.

Comment: @PeterSmith but of course, this is really an oversimplification. PIN diodes have very frequency-depending behaviour, and OP doesn't tell us what kind doting to expect from P and N (and the both of us probably just guesses the base semiconductor for all three regions is silicone).

Comment: i understand and i agree with you but here we have i-p and p-n boundaries not p/i and i/n (pin diode is pin not ipn, i-type p-type n-type with this order like the picture) ....Also  for this structure what would be the energy band diagram? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this is homework related, so I'm not going to draw it. However you should be able to draw the band structure on paper, it's relatively easy to get a rough idea. The steps are:

1. First draw your three bulk regions - an intrinsic chunk, a p-type chunk, and an n-type chunk. Make sure to draw all three so that the band spacing in each is the same (it's the same material after all) and so that the Fermi levels line up. Also leave a gap of a centimetre on your paper between each one.

   You should know how the Fermi level moves with doping - compared to the intrinsic where it is somewhere near the middle, in n-type it moves closer to the conduction band, and in p-type it moves closer to the valence band
2. You can draw a straight line to join up all of the Fermi levels. This represents the Fermi level across the entire structure which will remain constant.
3. Join up your intrinsic and p-type such that the vacuum level in the p-type bends down and the intrinsic level bends up. Both bend in a gradual curve to meet in the middle.
4. Draw all of the other band edges to stay parallel to each other (they will all meet up like the vacuum level did).
5. Repeat (3) and (4) for the p-n junction.

You now have a rough drawing of your band diagram.

If you compare that to the band diagram of an NPN transistor, you should notice something interesting.

Comment: thanks for your answer you helped me a lot ....i understand it and i draw it .....but what do you mean that if i compare it with the npn , i will notice something interesting? i have only noticed that the only difference is in the intrinsic where fermi level is in the middle and for npn the first n-type is closer to conduction. Thanks again

Comment: Compare the shape of an [NPN transistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bjt_equilibrium_bands_v2.svg) with your IPN structure. They look eerily similar don't they?

Comment: yes,indeed, they look very similar!